# Should it be module or component Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have a Pagination component that depends on service.

I need to reuse it a component in some pages on the top and bottom positions.

Should I create a `pagination.module` where register pagination service and component, or just declare pagination component in `app.module`?

Also issue it that the Pagination component contains translate pipe: `| translate`.
This pipe is registered in `app.module` and not available in `PaginationComponent`

**Share Module is:**

```js
    @NgModule({
        imports: [CommonModule, HeaderModule, FooterModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule, FormsModule],
        declarations: [
            BadgeComponent,
            LegendaComponent,
            DateControlBadgeDirective,
            CollectionStatusDocsDirective,
            OrderFilterComponent,
            SortringComponent,
            SignDocumentComponent,
            NavNotificationsComponent,
            LoaderComponent,
            FilterComponent,
            DropdownExecutorsComponent,
            ListFilterPipe,
            SortByPipe,
            ApplicationNamePipe,
            PaginationComponent,
        ],
        exports: [
            BadgeComponent,
            SignDocumentComponent,
            LoaderComponent,
            SortringComponent,
            FilterComponent,
            DropdownExecutorsComponent,
            LegendaComponent,
            ApplicationNamePipe,
            PaginationComponent,
            DateControlBadgeDirective,
            CollectionStatusDocsDirective,
            HeaderModule,
            FooterModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            MaterialModule,
            FormsModule,
            ListFilterPipe,
            SortByPipe,
            ApplicationNamePipe,
        ],
    })
    export class SharedModule {}
```

**App module is:**

```js
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            AppRoutingModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                    deps: [HttpClient],
                },
            }),
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            MaterialModule,
            HeaderModule,
            FooterModule,
            DashboardModule,
            OrdersDistributionModule,
            OrdersExecutionModule,
        ],
        providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'ru' }],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: every component/directive/pipe should be a part of some module in the app (only one). If you need use component in two or more modules, you need to move component to shared/feature module, and import that module to module where you want to get the component/pipe/directive.

TranslatePipe is a part of `TranslateModule` (if you use NgxTranslate), so to use `TranslatePipe` in your component - you should import `TranslateModule` to module where your component is declared.

more details: https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules#feature-modules

Notice: All that you import to AppModule will be a part of main bundle (will be loaded on every page in your App) so if you use pagination only in lazy-loaded modules, better to move it to PaginationModule and import that module to modules where you need PaginationComponent.

Comment: Should I import `TranslateModule.forRoot({})` also in ShareModule and AppModule?  And share module always must be imported to app.module?

Comment: I have imported translateModule to shareModule and it works, should I add translateModule to export in shareModule and remove translateModule from app module?

Comment: You should have `.forRoot()` only in your AppModule, in other modules import just `TranslateModule`, more info: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern

Comment: `forRoot()` in NgxTranslate provide loaders and sources for translates (it should be called only once). So if you call 'forRoot' in SharedModule you get duplicates of translates in the app. If you import to `SharedModule` only `TranslateModule` you get access to translate directive/pipe, those pipes/directives will be using your translates loaded once  by initialization in AppModule (so you share your translates across all modules in the app).

Answer (score 1):

Create it as a component and declare the component in you app.module or any other module.
If you are declaring the Pagination component in you app.module then it can access your translate pipe

Comment: Yes, I did that but pipe translate is not available, but I have registered pagination component in sharemodule, and share module imported to app.module, it is okay?

Comment: is your pipe available in export[] of app.module?? if not you will not be able to use it in shared module components

Comment: can you update app.module and shared module code in you question ?

Comment: i can not see translate in your declaration array

Comment: it is in app.module, look again

Comment: But I did not import shareModule in appModule, should I?

Comment: Maybe move `TranslateModule.forRoot({`}) to shareModule?

Comment: I have added export `    exports: [TranslateModule],` `in app.module`. It does not work

Comment: Where can I read that shareModule must be added in app.module?

Answer (score 0):

- First create shared module and register the

  TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
  provide: TranslateLoader,
  useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
  deps: [HttpClient],
  },
  })

  inside shared module and export the TranslateModule
- Then import the shared module in to  AppModule or any feature modules
- then create the service and PaginationComponent inside the shared folder and register in
  shared module
- then  export PaginationComponent

now you can use transaltion pipe and PaginationComponent in any feature module

please look [Angular 5 and ngx-translate with shared module loose translations if refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559743/angular-5-and-ngx-translate-with-shared-module-loose-translations-if-refresh)